# Set width of grid column with dynamic number of columns

Tags: css, angular, css-grid

Is it possible to set width of columns in grid when we don't know the number and order of them?

I have a dynamically rendering data. For example:

```
  dataArray = [
{
  title: 'A',
  data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
},
{
  title: 'B',
  data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
},
{
  title: 'C',
  data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
},
{
  title: 'D',
  data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
},
  ];
```

I 'm displaying it as grid in this way:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column" *ngFor="let d of dataArray">
    <div>{{ d.title }}</div>
    <div *ngFor="let data of d.data">
      <div>{{ data }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
}

.column {
  grid-row: none;
}
```

Now I want to set width to some columns. For example I want to set width of column:

- title: A - width 100px
- title: D - width: 150px.

I want to set those widths by titles, I don't know in witch order those column will render and how many of them will be. And I want the other columns to fit the content. I tried with `grid-template-columns` but I missed. Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: You can set a dynamic style using the binding `[style.width]="width"`, where `width` is a variable in your JS code

Comment: When I just set width on column that causes break between column with set width and the next one. I want the other columns to fit the content.

Comment: I don't know if this works, but try setting the width to `fit-content` as default value instead of a fixed value

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: `grid-auto-columns: min-content;` should work

Comment: but I dont want min-content of grid